# What is the best way to sync data among a small number of users in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization

As the header indicates, I am looking for the simplest way to sync user-generated data (Integers, Booleans, NSDates, etc) among a small number of individuals (at this point, I am just thinking of sharing data between two people). Within the app, users can populate an array with instances of a custom object and this data is used to populate a UITableview. Assuming all users in the select group have synced their devices they should all see the same data in the tableview.

My original idea was to write to a json file in a shared Dropbox or Google Drive folder. After looking around online, however, I found that this method is likely to lead to data corruption. Cloudkit only allows public or private (single account) syncing, nothing in between. I have seen some posts that recommend using Parse, but that service is now on its way out.

Does anyone know of a (preferably free) way to do this?

Comment: Do you plan to just have 2 or 3 users on your app, or do you plan for your app to have infinite users but interactions only occur between 2 or 3? If the latter, I'd suggest Firebase.

Comment: CloudKit will work for this using the public database. You just need to control what portions of the public data that each user sees in the app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For the time being, the app is for personal use and will have only a few users.  However, I would like the option to scale it up and release it on the App Store in the future. Having looked at Firebase's website, it seems promising. I will check it out!

Comment: Thanks, rmaddy. I thought about that, but couldn't find any resources on how to go about getting users to be able to access each other's - and only each other's - data (i.e. how to control what portions of public data users see). I am brand new to Cloudsync. Do you have anything you can recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

CloudKit databases - CloudKit's database system has the concept of a public database which does exactly what you want. It's fairly easy to use as well, and is "free" with an Apple developer account. The only downside is that it's for Apple devices only (AFAIK).

Firebase - Google's Firebase is basically identical to CloudKit in concept and features, but runs on multiple platforms. It is tied to the Google ecosystem, so your uses all need to provide a Google account to use it, but that's a small issue these days.

Realm - from a pure usability perspective, Realm is BY FAR the easiest data storage solution I've seen on iOS. However, it's sharing functionality is currently limited, CloudKit support is scheduled but currently all there is is [this](https://github.com/BellAppLab/RealmCloudKit). If you only need local storage *for now*, then definitely keep this on your list.

No matter which engine you choose, users would be limited to certain views of the data through your own code. I would suggest that you save every record with a username of the creator, and then have another table containing read/write permissions, so for instance, the entry for "maurymarkowitz" has "bobsmith,ronsmith,jonsmith". You can retrieve these entries on login and then use them as the inputs to the query-by-example both systems use for getting records.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all of the helpful responses. I ended up using cloudkit/coredata and it serves my purpose just fine. I simply used the public option and gave each set of users who are sharing data with each other a unique identifier, which  is appended to any records they upload. When a user syncs their data with the cloud the application performs a query for only those records that contain the user's identifier. This way, multiple users can sync data among themselves even though they do not share an iCloud account.